# DATEADD not working for the last 30 days

Tags: sql-server

When I run this query, it seems to work great when I run it against the date 2015-4-11.  However, if I query against the last 3 days it returns the values in year, month, and week as the same.  The day is accurate, but it doesn't seem to correctly add everything else.

```
declare @today date = '2015-1-1'
    select
        [Day Total]   = sum(case when [AccountingDate] < dateadd(DAY, 1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
        [Week Total]  = sum(case when [AccountingDate] < dateadd(WEEK, 1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
        [Month Total] = sum(case when [AccountingDate] < dateadd(MONTH, 1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
        [Year Total]  = sum([Amount])
    from
        [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay]
    where
        [AccountingDate] >= @today and [AccountingDate] < dateadd(year, 1, @today);
```

Comment: Is your `AccountingDate`  a `DATE` value or a `DATETIME`?

Comment: AccountingDate is the date and time at which an event happened. In the table there is a Date Column and a AccountingDate column.  Both have The date and time in them.

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: I can't supply any sample data.  I didn't consider the future date as a possibility.  How would I initiate this query to start with the last entry item instead of a future date.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's aggregating what you ask of it, there's just likely nothing in your table between tomorrow and a month from tomorrow.  What do you want it to be aggregating? Maybe the logic needs a tweak.

Comment: I don't want this going into the future.  I wanted this to take today's date, then go in the past and sum everything up.

Comment: So you want from today to 1 day ago, 1 week ago, and 1 month ago?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought was happening here.  /me puts on stupid hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a recent date, you're looking for values where the `[AccountingDate]` is less than some future date.

If you add a day/week/month to Today, then all data will be prior to those dates unless you have future data in your table:

```
declare @today date = '2015-05-12'
    SELECT dateadd(DAY, 1, @today)
          ,dateadd(week, 1, @today)
          ,dateadd(month, 1, @today)
```

Returns:  `2015-05-13, 2015-05-19, 2015-06-12`

So `[AccountingDate]` is always less than those dates if your table only has data through today.

If you actually want to aggregate from Today to 1 day back, 1 week back, and 1 month back, you need to use `-1` in your `DATEADD()`, use `>`, and modify your `WHERE` criteria, something like:

```
declare @today date = '2015-1-1'
    select
        [Day Total]   = sum(case when [AccountingDate] > dateadd(DAY, -1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
        [Week Total]  = sum(case when [AccountingDate] > dateadd(WEEK, -1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
        [Month Total] = sum(case when [AccountingDate] > dateadd(MONTH, -1, @today) then [Amount] else 0 end),
        [Year Total]  = sum([Amount])
 from
        [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay]
 where
        [AccountingDate] <= @today and [AccountingDate] > dateadd(MONTH, -1, @today);
```

Note:  When comparing a `DATETIME` to a `DATE` any time after midnight will be considered greater than the `DATE` value, so you'll want to make sure you're not excluding values, either by casting the `DATETIME` as `DATE` or ensuring you've accounted for the range properly, i.e.:  < tomorrow's `DATE` instead of <= today's `DATE` to include records from today that have a time after `00:00:00.000`

Comment: Thanks I did a few more tweaks and your guidance got me on point!